# Regex in php: Compulsory second occurence of word

Tags: php, regex

I need to match a few urls for an application I'm working on;

So, I've got this reference string:

```
content/course/32/lesson/61/content/348
```

and I need a pattern that matches either

```
content
```

OR

```
content/course/[number]/lesson/[number]/content/[number]
```

What I've done so far is come up with this pattern:

```
$my_regex = "/content(\/?|(\/course\/\d{1,4}\/lesson\/\d{1,4}\/content\/\d{1,4}))$/";
```

which however has the following problem: This string returns a match which should otherwise not:

```
content/course/32/lesson/61/content
```

I'm thinking that it's got something to do with the word `content` repeating twice but I'm not entirely sure.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If your pattern contains lots of slashes then it's easier to use a different regex delimiter, rather than having to escape everything.

Comment: Try removing this part`(\/?|`

Comment: Try removing this part`(\/?|` and matching last bracket `)` before `$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the match is the alternation.

```
content\/?$
```

matches

```
content/course/32/lesson/61/content
```

To fix this, add a `^` (beginning of line) to the start of your regex to ensure the entire string is matched and not only the ending:

```
/^content(\/?|(\/course\/\d{1,4}\/lesson\/\d{1,4}\/content\/\d{1,4}))$/
```

[See it in action](https://regex101.com/r/tN1sT1/1)

Comment: plus 1, i was thinking the same :)

Comment: @ndn Great explanation. Easy fix. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
/(^content\/?|content\/course\/\d{1,4}\/lesson\/\d{1,4}\/content\/\d{1,4})$/
```